# Enable EPEL with cloud-init via "User Data" (Amazon Linux)

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, user-data, cloud-init, epel

I'm trying to install the `p7zip` package after launching an Amazon Linux-based EC2 instance in AWS via the "User Data" feature (using `cloud-init`):

```
#cloud-config
repo_update: true
repo_upgrade: all

packages:
 - p7zip
```

However since `p7zip` isn't available in the normal repos and requires EPEL to be enabled, it does not appear to be fetching the package properly.

My question is: using `cloud-init`, how do I enable EPEL before fetching packages when initialising the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 2):

```
#cloud-config
# vim: syntax=yaml
#
# Add yum repository configuration to the system
#
# The following example adds the file /etc/yum.repos.d/epel_testing.repo
# which can then subsequently be used by yum for later operations.
yum_repos:
    # The name of the repository
    epel-testing:
        # Any repository configuration options
        # See: man yum.conf
        #
        # This one is required!
        baseurl: http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/testing/5/$basearch
        enabled: false
        failovermethod: priority
        gpgcheck: true
        gpgkey: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
        name: Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - Testing
```

Answer (score 2):

For more recent versions of Amazon Linux, you need to add the following to cloud-config file:

```
yum_repos:
    epel_custom:
        name: Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
        baseurl: http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
        mirrorlist: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
        failovermethod: priority
        enabled: true
        gpgcheck: true
        gpgkey: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

[Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wallix/awless-templates/7645ab8d806e9d67610b4b4334fc9a8af7d79e5b/userdata/install_awless_suite.yml) is an example of a working cloud-config file that can be used at boot as [userdata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following sections will enable EPEL with GPG.  Note that the key is imported at initial boot.

```
#cloud-config
bootcmd:
  - [ cloud-init-per, once, gpg-key-epel, rpm, "--import", "https://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7" ]
yum_repos:
  epel:
    name: EPEL
    mirrorlist: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch
    enabled: true
    gpgcheck: true
repo_update: true
repo_upgrade: all
```

From https://github.com/trajano/terraform-docker-swarm-aws/blob/master/common.cloud-config